# Hibernate Multi tenancy issue with H2: wrong schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am building an application that uses PostgreSQL in production and H2 for local development and tests using latest versions of Hibernate and Java 8.

The implementation works fine for PostgreSQL, but causes issues when using H2. If I call the same endpoint to create an entity for 2 different tenants, all entities are created in the same (first) schema that was called.

**getConnection() in my MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl:**

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
    connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
    return connection;
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Note that even though the **correct** `tenantIdentifier` is passed into getConnection, the query is still run against the wrong schema.

Could this be an issue with the Hikari Connection Pool caching the connections and not propagating the `setSchema()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug with H2 and it's query cache not picking up a change in schema.

Disabling the query cache completely works around the issue:

`jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;QUERY_CACHE_SIZE=0`

Created a bug report: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1952